# How do I add prerecorded speech to iOS app

Tags: ios, embedded-resource, speech

Have started working on my first app for iOS. (Normally I'm a Python guy). The app has inspirational advice, the client has recorded speech/narration that they would like to embed and play in the app. I don't want sound files to be separate in iTunes. Is it possible to embed player functionality and sound segments so a user can simply press a button and hear the speech?

Comment: `AVAudioPlayer` is your friend.

Comment: Look for any question on how to play audio,  and then find a tutorial on App Thinning assuming you have a significant amount of áudio to play back.